# Android Studio, Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android, android-studio

when I debug my project, there is an error "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs"

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
Error:
Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.5.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86
is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-22:19 to override.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kelompok22.veterinarycare">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".StartActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you share the list of your gradle dependencies once ?

Comment: @GaganBatra 
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation-java:1.2.0'

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `Gradle File(Module App)` find and remove this line from your dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
```

Then `Sync` Gradle to apply changes.

The problem should resolve.

Comment: error disappeared after I removed implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation-java:1.2.0'
but i want to use those dependencies

Comment: Nice observation - in this case use the Kotlin version intead of java i.e. replace `navigation-java` with `implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation:1.3.1'`